# CSS hover not working when wrapped with media query

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-web

I am using [react-native-web](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/) and NextJS and want to change the hover styles depending on breakpoint using media queries. Without media queries, this code works on hover:

```js
    packshotHoverHighlighted: {
        ':hover': {
            marginTop: 'calc(-1.3%)',
            marginBottom: 'calc(1.3%)',
            transform: 'scale(1.05)',
        },
        transition: '0.1s ease-in',
```

But when wrapped with a media query, the properties inside `:hover` are not present in the DOM, although the media query and `transition` is:

```js
packshotHoverHighlighted: {
        [`@media (min-width: ${Breakpoint.MD + 1}px) and (max-width: ${Breakpoint.L}px)`]: {
            ':hover': {
                marginTop: 'calc(-2.5%)',
                marginBottom: 'calc(2.5%)',
                transform: 'scale(1.09)',
            },
            transition: '0.1s ease-in',
        },
```

Why does `:hover` work when used without a media query but doesn't work when used with one?

Comment: A workaround could be to use CSS variables instead, and change their values in the media query.

Comment: Thanks @RickardElimää, so you mean use plain CSS? Unfortunately our tooling is not set up to process / handle vanilla CSS or SCSS

Comment: Or somehow incorporating these inside the media query? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: As I said, it's a workaround. I was thinking in the line of these - what you're talking about in your second comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-css-variables-react-native/